# Loopback 3.0 vs Loopback 4.0

Tags: node.js, nodes, loopbackjs

We are starting a new application which will only be used for building REST APIs. We have used loopback 3.0 in the past but now when loopback 4.0 is available I was wondering what is the best option: 3.0 or 4.0.

Is loopback 4.0 stable enough for a complex production app, as there was a number of issues we faced with loopback 3.0 when it was new?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**LoopBack 4.0** (GA) is the next generation of the LoopBack framework, with a completely rewritten core foundation and significantly improved programming model (when compared against the previous version).

To facilitate migration between LoopBack 3 and LoopBack 4, you can mount your LoopBack 3 application on top of a LoopBack 4 project and can envision for potential issues which may arise in future. See [Migrating-from-LoopBack-3](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Migrating-from-LoopBack-3.html) for more info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the major concern is loopback 4.0 mature enough like loopback 3.0?

Comment: it is production ready - more informations:
https://strongloop.com/strongblog/loopback-4-ga

Comment: Yeah.. @akkonrad is spot on!. You can rely on it!.

Answer (score 1):

As I already know, In december **Loopback 3** support will be cut from ibm. For that reason **Loopback4** will be great for creating new application. But there are certain problems in **Loopback4** also. For example, relations are not quite enough, if you are planning to use complex database collections.

Of course it will be updated and you will be able to do whatever you want. But now it is still in development phase. So it can give you hard times when you were developing your app.